# Conducting transactions on Bitcoin and Tron platforms with PHP

Tags: php, bitcoin, cryptocurrency, tron

For example, I want to transfer 1 bitcoin from account number 1 to account number 2. How can I connect to Bitcoin or Tron network with php and transfer bitcoins from one account to another?

I tried to do this with Fenguoz/tron-php library, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Bitcoin:

1. Use the `bitwasp/bitcoin-php` library for PHP.
2. Create private keys for sender and receiver, along with their addresses.
3. Fetch UTXOs (Unspent Transaction Outputs) for the sender's address using an API or a Bitcoin node.
4. Build a transaction using the UTXOs and specify the recipient's address.
5. Sign the transaction with the sender's private key.
6. Broadcast the transaction to the Bitcoin network using an API or a Bitcoin node.

Tron:

1. Use the `Fenguoz/tron-php` library for PHP.
2. Create private keys for sender and receiver, along with their addresses.
3. Connect to a Tron full node using its URL.
4. Create a transaction object specifying the sender, receiver, and amount.
5. Sign the transaction with the sender's private key.
6. Broadcast the signed transaction to the Tron network using the full node's API.
7. Check the result of the broadcast to ensure the transaction was successful.
   consider implementing proper error handling and security measures before deploying any code for real transactions.